# Need to add items to list from checkedlistbox and remove some

Tags: c#

There's a checklist that contains strings . 
There is a for each loop that checks the  checked items and then add those items to the list of strings that's called *mylist* only if they aren't added already.

What i need is to check for the not checked items in the listbox  and remove the strings from *mylist* after unchecking item from box .

Basicaly i have a list called *mylist* i need to add whatever checked item from checkedboxlist to *mylist* and whenever i uncheck an item delete the same string from *mylist* .

Suggest some solutions. Thanks  in advance .

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: please update the question with code snippet

Comment: No code, but I'd guess `foreach (var box in checkboxList) { if (box.IsChecked) { myList.Add(box.Text;}}`

Answer (score 0):

The below code has a `foreach` loop that iterates through a list of `CheckBox`es and then checks if each item is checked or not. If not checked then gets the index of that entry from `myList` and uses `RemoveAt` method to remove that entry from the list using the index.

```
foreach (var item in checkboxList) 
{ 
   if (!item.IsChecked) 
   {
       int index = myList.IndexOf(item);
       if(index != -1)
           myList.RemoveAt(index);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, be so kind and review your next question ([How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))...

Take advantage of the event `anyCheckedListBox.ItemCheck` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public class Form1 : Form {

ListBox anyListBox;
CheckedListBox anyCheckedListBox;

public Form1() {
 anyListBox = new ListBox();
 Controls.Add(anyListBox);
 anyCheckedListBox = new CheckedListBox();
 anyCheckedListBox.Items.Add("test1");
 anyCheckedListBox.Items.Add("test2");
 anyCheckedListBox.Items.Add("test3");
 anyCheckedListBox.ItemCheck += AnyCheckedListBox_ItemCheck;
 Controls.Add(anyCheckedListBox);
}

private void AnyCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
        anyListBox.Items.Add(anyCheckedListBox.Items[e.Index]);
    else
        anyListBox.Items.Remove(anyCheckedListBox.Items[e.Index]);
}
}
```

Beware that the strings have to be unique with this quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

The naïve implementation would be to add a call to [`List.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) in your loop if the item is not checked. Assuming the code you have is similar to @AustinFrench's comment, something like:

```
foreach (var box in checkboxList)
{
    if (box.IsChecked && !myList.Contains(box.Text))
    {
        // if it's checked, add it to the list if it's not already there
        myList.Add(box.Text);
    }
    else if (!box.IsChecked)
    {
        // if it's not checked, try to remove it from the list
        myList.Remove(box.Text);
    }
}
```

Note that you do *not* need to check whether an item exists before calling `List.Remove`. It will simply return false if the item does not exist.

---

Additionally note this is an O(n^2) operation. It is potentially checking the entire contents of `myList` for each item in your checkboxlist. If the lists are long, you may get better performance by sorting the lists first and making a single simultaneous pass through the pair (or at least sort `myList` so you can search it more efficiently).

Alternatively, consider completely replacing the contents of `myList` instead. This requires only a single pass through your checkboxlist:

```
myList.Clear();
foreach (var box in checkboxList)
{
    if (box.IsChecked)
        myList.Add(box.Text);
}
```

Or, using LINQ and taking advantage of [`List.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
myList.Clear();
myList.AddRange(checkboxList.Where(box => box.IsChecked).Select(box => box.Text));
```